# Denote case sensitivity on printed media

Tags: hyperlinks, social-media, letter-case

I made some business cards for my wife for her balloon twisting side business. Nothing too professional as is it just something she likes to do on weekends.

She has a Facebook page that she just started up and I wanted to give a link to said page on the cards. I would have to use a shortened URL which is fine as [Facebook does support those](https://www.facebook.com/notes/hyperarts-web-design/set-a-custom-urlusername-for-your-facebook-page/457770375843)*. However the page mentions a stipulation that

> ***NOTE: You must have 25 fans to set a username for your Page!**

So I figured instead I would try for a short goo.gl URL. I made one it tested OK. I noticed the mixed case in the URL and tested to see if it was case-sensitive and it was. I figured that next to no one would figure it out and would just type it all in lowercase. Doing so would lead them to Google's 404 page.

Is there something I could do that would denote case-sensitivity on a link on printed media that would be less obtrusive than:

> (http:// page.com/4ReT (case sensitive)

This is what it would have looked like. Note the link is bogus (for now at least)

[image: eExample Image]

In the end I used a tinyurl.org address where I could customize the link to be real words.

---

* I didn't notice at first that the page was not official or I should have at least tested. [That facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/notes/hyperarts-web-design/set-a-custom-urlusername-for-your-facebook-page/457770375843) that was linked is dated or otherwise incorrect now. Pages have no # of fan restrictions. I just created a short link with no issue... now I feel bad about the money spent with the tinyURL. My question still stands though.

Comment: Forgive me if this is off-topic as it is not web content. Read some of the help and I wasn't convinced it wasn't. Figured this might be the best place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use a human-readable link in anything intended for print.**

The case sensitivity is only one part of the problem with the short URL.  Besides this, it also looks like gibberish, making it hard to remember and enter.

There are various ways of generating a human-readable link (presumably you found one already in the Facebook setting).

Some URL shorteners offer a human-readable version.  I don't have any personal experience with these, but bit.do is the first one I found online that does this.  The [wikipedia page on URL shortening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening) claims that Google offers this option, as well, but I couldn't find this feature on Goo.gl.

You could also register your own domain name, of course.  It costs money, but not that much, and might be worthwhile even for a casual business.

**Also consider adding a QR code.**

Many URL shorteners (including Google) ofter this by default.  It provides an even easier way to access your site from print media.  However, not everyone knows how to use these, so it can't completely replace a link.

Comment: Yeah. I don't expect people to look at those and want to type that in the browser. In the end I think you are right in that there is no way to make that kind of link work without causing confusion for the reader. I actually got the printing company to change the link before they printed it. So it had a human readable facebook address now. Thanks for the help. Adding a QR code would not hurt for the people that know what those are. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a service that let's you set the nice name for your link is not just more readable, as you can often request to track stats on the link to see how many people went to it and when.

E.g.
http://tiny.cc/drunkhoff
Links to an uhm... Not so classy picture of David Hasselhoff.
Appending a tilde'~' to the URL takes you to a page that tracks stats (if you request the option when you create the short URL)
http://tiny.cc/drunkhoff~

Comment: That is exactly what I did. In my question _In the end I used a tinyurl.org address where I could customize the link to be real words._

Comment: Yeah I was just trying to indicate that there is another upside that you get from a custom URL... Usage stats ;-)